# Jquery search box

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a responsive Jquery searchbox.
Things I'm trying to do:

- The DIV should collapse and the search field should disappear when the window gets smaller.
- When collapsed, the DIV should expand and the search field appear whenever clicked on the DIV. The DIV should collapse again and the search field disappear when clicked on or clicked anywhere else.

I've created a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/270krg8c/7/

HTML:

```
<div id="pagewrap">
    <div id="user4">
        <div class="search">
            <form action="/" method="post" class="form-inline">
                <label for="mod-search-searchword" class="element-invisible" aria- invalid="false"></label>
                <input name="searchword" id="mod-search-searchword" maxlength="200" class="inputbox search-query" type="search" size="20" placeholder="Zoeken...">
                <input type="hidden" name="task" value="search">
                <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_search">
                <input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="144">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#pagewrap {
    width: 500px;
}

.search {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px -1px #ccc, -5px 5px 10px -1px #ccc;
    background-color: #AEAEAE;
    border-color: #959595;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-style: none solid solid solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 244px;
    height: 45px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    background-image: url("http://s8.postimg.org/94l8aqeld/search_Button.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
}

input[type="search"] {
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 9px 0px 9px 9px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #pagewrap {
        width: 95%;
    }

    .search {
        width: 45px;
    }

    .search.clicked {
        width: 244px;
    }

    input[type="search"] {
        display: none !important;
        overflow: hidden !important;
    }

    .search.clicked > input[type="search"] {
        display: initial;
        width: 160px;
    };
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('.search').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

There are 2 things I can't get to work:

- The search field does not appear when clicked on the DIV.
- I'm very new at Jquery and cant find a good script for collapsing the DIV when clicked anywhere else.

I'm hoping someone can help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are not jQuery, but CSS.

1. Move all the search-related stuff below the rest of your stylesheet. Some of your stylesheet is causing issues with this CSS. That's the cascading part of [cascading style sheets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#Sources).
2. In your media query change :

   ```
   .search.clicked > input[type="search"]{
   ```

   to

   ```
   .search.clicked input[type="search"]{
   ```

   since the `>` selects only direct children of `.search.clicked`.